# OCMockito / OCHamcrest verify array contains object property

Tags: objective-c, ocmockito, ochamcrest

I'm creating an application which adds some local notifications.
This is my test

```
- (void)testFirstLogin {

//some initials array
NSArray *withoutFriends = @[@"a", @"b", @"c", @"e", @"f"];
NSArray *withFriends = @[@"v", @"w", @"x", @"y", @"z"];

//my service which add local notifications
LocalNotificationService *service = [LocalNotificationService sharedInstance];
service.lastLoginDate = nil;

//UIApplication mock
UIApplication *application = mock([UIApplication class]);
service.applictation = application;

//method which adds notifications
[service addNotificationScheduleFirstLoginWithNoFriendsArray:withoutFriends friendsExistArray:withFriends];

//In this method I create UILocalNotification
/*
 UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
 localNotification.alertBody = text;
 */

//and add it to schedule
//[self.applictation scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

[verifyCount(application, times(1)) scheduleLocalNotification:anything()]; }
```

This is correct and verification is success.
But I need verify if my UILocalNotification object property **alertBody** is in **withoutFriends** array.
Is there a way for this ?

Comment: Do you know in advance what `alertBody` will be? Like `@"a"`?

Comment: There is no friends in this scenario so I know that **alertBody** will be a random value from **withoutFriends** array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a matcher `isIn` which I see is [missing from the README](https://github.com/hamcrest/OCHamcrest/issues/77). Together with the `hasProperty` matcher, we can write:

```
[verifyCount(application, times(1)) scheduleLocalNotification:hasProperty(@"alertBody", isIn(withoutFriends))];
```